# how to import reducer to store.js from createSlice @reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

how to export todos reducer from todosSlice by using createSlice @reduxjs/toolkit and how to import it to store by using configureStore

here is my todosSlice file :

```
    //todosSlice file
    import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    const todosSlice = createSlice({
       name: 'todos',
       initialState: [],
       reducers: {
          addTodos: (state, action) => {
             state.push(action.payload)
          },
          removeTodos: (state, action) => {
             state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload.id)
          }
       }
    });
    
    export const { addTodos, removeTodos } = todosSlice.actions;
    export default todosSlice.reducer; //this reducer that i want to import to store file
```

and here is my store file :

```
    import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    //and here is supposed where the reducer imported

    const store = configureStore({
       reducer: {
          todos: //here todos reducer should be.
          anyReducer: anyReducer,
       }
    });
    
    export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `export default` statement in your `TodosSlice` allows you to import the function with the name you want. So here what you could do.

```js
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import todosReducer from 'path/to/your/TodosSlice';

const store = configureStore({
   reducer: {
      todos: todosReducer,
      anyReducer: anyReducer,
   }
});
```